# Writing in edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have searched the internet but I didn't get a proper answer. Is there any way to get the information when the user clicked on the `EditText` or writing something in the `EditText`?  Please help.

Comment: are you luking for search option ?

Answer (score 0):

for user clicks, check developer site:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29

in order to listen user type, check this one:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29

Answer (score 0):

Assume your EditText has been set up in your layout XML file and given the ID `yourEditText`

```
EditText edtText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
String text = edtText.getText.toString();
```

To listen when a key is pressed you need to set a KeyListener. `edtText.setOnKeyListener(this)` then implement the `OnKeyListener` interface in your class and implement the required methods.